# Let $X$ be the number of faces that never show up in 15 rolls. What is p.m.f of $X$?

Tags: probability

Suppose a fair die is rolled for 15 times. Let $X$ be the number of faces that never show up in these 15 rolls. What is p.m.f of $X$?

I thought about each case where $x$ goes from 0 to 5. If $x$ is $0$, then 6 out of 15 trials should yield faces from 1 to 6 once each, so I figured ${}_{15} \mathrm{ C }_6 (1/6)^6$. If $x$ is between 1 and 5, I picked $x$ faces that will never appear out of the 6 faces, thought that the faces excluding $x$ should appear 15 times.
 Thus $$f_X(X=0) = {}_{15} \mathrm{ C }_6 (1/6)^6$$
$$f_X(X=1,2,3,4,5)={}_6\mathrm{C}_x\left(\frac{6-x}{6}\right)^{15}$$

Is my answer wrong?

---

Thanks to your help, I thought about it further and realized that this was clearly a question of inclusion and exclusion principles. However, the solution I came up with is slightly different from the one in the link below. I would like to know where my solution is wrong. My solution is below.$$P(X=5)=P(X\ge 5)={}_{6} \mathrm{ C }_5\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{15}$$$$P(X=4)=P(X\ge 4)-P(X\ge 5)={}_{6} \mathrm{ C }_4\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^{15}-{}_{6} \mathrm{ C }_5\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{15}$$And finally$$f_X(x)=\sum_{i=x}^5(-1)^{i-x}{}_{6} \mathrm{ C }_i\left(1-\frac{i}{6}\right)^{15}$$However the solution to the link below is$$f_X(x)={}_{6} \mathrm{ C }_x\sum_{i=x}^6{}_{6-x} \mathrm{ C }_{i-x}(-1)^{i-x}(1-\left(\frac{i}{6}\right))^{15}$$It looks a lot different, but it's not. The difference is the addition and subtraction terms multiplied by their respective chosen number. For example,according to solution of link$$P(X=4)={}_{6} \mathrm{ C }_4\left(\frac{2}{6}\right)^{15}-5{}_{6} \mathrm{ C }_5\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)^{15}$$The subtraction term was multiplied by 5.

Please tell me what I'm missing

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @Shaun Thank you for kind feedback. I have just edited it.

Comment: An answer on Quora which [uses inclusion-exclusion](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-probability-mass-function-of-X-when-X-is-the-number-of-faces-that-never-show-up-in-15-rolls-of-dice) and is correct, so your answer is wrong.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer With your help, I've have progress. But there's still questions. Please check the additional question edited above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability of drawing three different colours without order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3265930/probability-of-drawing-three-different-colours-without-order)